# Mac Calendar.app not synced, different to iOS

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, calendar

A calendar I am subscribed to is up-to-date and represented accurately on my iPhone, but not on my MacBook.

I keep refreshing calendars ⌘R, quitting and reopening Calendar.app, went into preferences to set "refresh calendars" to manually, and then refreshed, but still I can't see events that my iPhone is showing me to exist.

Comment: Both on the same Apple ID? Both logged in?

Comment: @SolarMike yes asdfa

Answer (score 0):

have you made sure that, on macOS, all calendars are ticked?
[image: where to tick all calendars in the macOS cal app]

Comment: Yes, they are all ticked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as you said this is a subscribed calendar that it is not one you can edit, just one you can view? Check calendar info on macOS and compare with the iPhone. On phone, click information icon next to calendar then select Subscription Details, and compare URI with that shown on macOS (select calendar then Cmd+I to open info). Verify that the subscription link is actually the same on both devices. Check on macOS what you have set as the calendar auto-refresh rate. Worst case scenario, remove the calendar completely from your Mac and re-subscribe.

Comment: When I click Calendars > (i) on iOS, I only see "Edit Calendar - Calendar (greyed out) - COLOUR - NOTIFICATIONS Event Alerts - AVAILABILITY " , no option "Subscription details"

Comment: Check Settings > Calendar > Accounts. More options should show up there. If it is working as expected on iOS you are only looking for details here to verify that it is not subscribed differently on macOS.